# Пример по умолчанию выдает: "отказано в авторизации"

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api

Запускаю пример по умолчанию, созданный средой для проекта `Web API`:

**ValuesController.cs**

```
// GET api/values
public IEnumerable<string> Get()
{
    return new string[] { "value1", "value2" };
}

// GET api/values/5
public string Get(int id)
{
    return "value";
}

// POST api/values
public void Post([FromBody]string value)
{
}

// PUT api/values/5
public void Put(int id, [FromBody]string value)
{
}

// DELETE api/values/5
public void Delete(int id)
{
}
```

**Сhrome**

В браузере Chrome указываю `http://localhost:58534/api/values` и в окне появляется:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Internet Explorer**

В браузере IE указываю `http://localhost:58534/api/values` и скачивается какой-то странный файл (`values.cwshbzg.partial`) и он пустой.

**Вопрос**

Почему так происходит? Если говорить про авторизацию, то она мне пока не нужна. Хочу чтобы сервис работал без необходимости авторизоваться.

Comment: А атрибут [Authorize] для класса этого контроллера случаем не стоит?

Comment: Да именно он и был. Удалил `[Authorize]` и заработало.